# Notifications not sending in Tauri

Tags: notifications, tauri

I'm building a simple desktop app using Tauri and Svelte but I'm having trouble with the [`notification` module](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/modules/notification). I have allowlisted all APIs in `tauri.conf.json`.

**The code below runs and prints `permissionGranted` as `true` (line 10) but the `sendNotification`s seem to have no effect.**

```
const notify = async () => {
    let permissionGranted = await isPermissionGranted();
    if (!permissionGranted) {
        const permission = await requestPermission();
        permissionGranted = permission === "granted";
    }
    if (permissionGranted) {
        sendNotification("Tauri is awesome!");
        sendNotification({ title: "TAURI", body: "Tauri is awesome!" });
        console.log(permissionGranted);
    }
}

notify();
```

**I also tried using the Notifications API in the console itself but nothing happens and the created Notification object has no properties.**

```
Notification.permission; // "granted"
const n = new Notification("New Message", { body: "hello" }); // {} empty object
```

**Platform and Versions**

```
Environment
  › OS: Mac OS 12.4.0 X64
  › Node.js: 17.2.0
  › npm: 8.13.2
  › pnpm: 6.11.0
  › yarn: 1.22.15
  › rustup: 1.25.1
  › rustc: 1.62.0
  › cargo: 1.62.0
  › Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-apple-darwin 

Packages
  › @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.0.5
  › @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.0.2
  › tauri [RUST]: 1.0.5,
  › tauri-build [RUST]: 1.0.4,
  › tao [RUST]: 0.12.2,
  › wry [RUST]: 0.19.0,

App
  › build-type: bundle
  › CSP: unset
  › distDir: ../public
  › devPath: http://localhost:8080/
  › framework: Svelte
  › bundler: Rollup
  › wry [RUST]: 0.19.0,
```

**`tauri.conf.json`**

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@tauri-apps/cli/schema.json",
  "build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
    "beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:8080",
    "distDir": "../public"
  },
  "package": {
    "productName": "d",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "all": true
    },
    "bundle": {
      "active": true,
      "category": "DeveloperTool",
      "copyright": "",
      "deb": {
        "depends": []
      },
      "externalBin": [],
      "icon": [
        "icons/32x32.png",
        "icons/128x128.png",
        "icons/128x128@2x.png",
        "icons/icon.icns",
        "icons/icon.ico"
      ],
      "identifier": "com.tauri.dev",
      "longDescription": "",
      "macOS": {
        "entitlements": null,
        "exceptionDomain": "",
        "frameworks": [],
        "providerShortName": null,
        "signingIdentity": null
      },
      "resources": [],
      "shortDescription": "",
      "targets": "all",
      "windows": {
        "certificateThumbprint": null,
        "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
        "timestampUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "security": {
      "csp": null
    },
    "updater": {
      "active": false
    },
    "windows": [
      {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 600,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "d",
        "width": 800
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an issue with the Tauri notifications API on MacOS in development mode.

[#4965](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4965)